# fontconfig library not found while configure for building octave 3.6

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to build Octave 3.6.1 on my 64bit ubuntu 11.10.  I was able to fix all other warning messages from configure except this one: 'fontconfig library not found'.  I tried to install libfontconfig, but apt-get uses libfontconfig1 instead of libfontconfig.  How can I let configure to use libfontconfig1 instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I fixed the problem.  I don't even know what steps I took, but I was able to compile Octave 3.6.1.  Unfortunately, the new Octave binary failed in 1 make check test. :(